# Cordova/Phonegap: Cannot add ANY platforms

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

My issue is as follows: **I cannot add any platforms to my Cordova/Phonegap project.** For example, I will show you the simple *'hello'* tutorial that is often referenced. This project was created using the the format:

cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

[Output when I try to do >cordova platform add android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNbb5.jpg)

---

I will also include my **system variables**:

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

ANT_HOME = C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.3

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171

PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools
```

---

Lastly, I want to note the following:

**Cordova version - 8.0.0**

**Phonegap Version - 8.0.0**

**npm Version - 6.1.0**

**Installed SDKs for android - 6.0, 7.0, 7.1.1, 8.0, 8.1**

Comment: Try `cordova platform add android@6.4.0`.  I wouldn't recommend 7.0.0 right now, most plugins aren't written to handle the changes yet.

Comment: @BShaps I see, thanks for the heads up on that!